# CryptographicException "Signing key is not loaded"

Tags: c#, .net, xml, signing

I have some code that tries to sign an XML document using a `X509Certificate2` cert:

```
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(_loginDetails.CertificateAsString);

        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(bytes, _loginDetails.CertKey, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
        Reference reference = new Reference("#MsgBody");

        XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
        reference.AddTransform(env);

        SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(doc);
        signedXml.AddReference(reference);
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
        signedXml.SigningKey = rsaKey;
        signedXml.ComputeSignature();

        // Get the XML representation of the signature and add to the SOAP Header
        XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();
        ...
```

This code work on 8 different customer machines and on my own machine, but we have 1 customer that get the error:

> Signing key is not loaded at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.ComputeSignature

I have gotten a copy of the certificate and password from the customer and it signs correctly on my developer machine without any error.

Does anyone have any more insight into why this can fail? Both the certificate and password are correct and it only fails on the customers server.
We are using `.NET 4.5`.

Comment: Environment problem.  Tricky to debug as I cant reproduce.  Look for differences.  Windows version/permissions/root certificates/etc.

Comment: I had the same error "Signing key is not loaded at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.ComputeSignature". The reason was that the used certificate was only the public part of the certificate without the private key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "solution" was to run our payment add-on as administrator on the machine. 
Not ideal as the rest of the code is built to run without administrator rights but I have not found any other solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Private key is not present to your certificate
so try to use your certificate instead of client certificate

Certificate should have private key